# sql sum a column and also return the last time stamp

Tags: sql-server, sum, grouping

I've got a table in SQL Server with several columns.  The relevant ones are:

name
distance
create_date

I have many people identified by name, and every few days they travel a certain distance.  For example:

```
name     distance     create_date
john     15           09/12/2014
john     20           09/22/2014
alex     10           08/15/2014
alex     12           09/05/2014
john     8            09/30/2014
alex     30           09/12/2014
```

What i would like is a query that for each person returns the sum of distance between two dates, and the create_date of the last entry during that date range, ordered by highest distance DESC.  For example, given a date range of 08/01/2014 to 09/25/2014 I would expect this:

```
name     distance     create_date
alex     52           09/12/2014
john     35           09/22/2014
```

I thought of trying to do this with a SUM query with a sub query to get the newest date in the range but I think this is not efficient.

Does someone have an idea for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(distance) AS distance,
       MAX(create_date) AS create_date
FROM   Table
WHERE  create_date >= '20140801' AND create_date < '20140925'
GROUP BY name
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9887e/2)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple sum and max functions for this.

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(distance) AS distance,
       MAX(create_date) AS create_date
FROM   theTable
WHERE  create_date >= @startDate AND create_date < @endDate
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY distance DESC
```