# sql server sum column to find out who reached a value first

Tags: sql-server, sum, grouping

I asked a question similar to this here:

[sql sum a column and also return the last time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25746457/sql-sum-a-column-and-also-return-the-last-time-stamp)

It turns out my use case was incorrect though so I need to make an adjustment to my question.

I've got a table in SQL Server with several columns.  The relevant ones are:

```
name
distance
create_date
```

I have many people identified by name, and every few days they travel a certain distance.  For example:

```
name     distance     create_date
john     15           09/12/2014
john     20           09/22/2014
alex     10           08/15/2014
alex     12           09/05/2014
alex     20           09/12/2014
john     8            09/30/2014
alex     30           09/14/2014
mike     12           09/10/2014
```

The query I need has 3 parameters:

```
@start_date
@end_date
@count
```

I need a query that between the two dates, returns for each person the distance traveled.  The trick though is that for each person I should sum to an amount just past the amount indicated in @count and return the date this was achieved, or if the person did not pass the @count then return the sum and last date of entry.  So for example, if I use the parameters:

```
@start_date=08/01/2014
@end_date=09/25/2014
@count=35
```

I would expect the following:

```
name     distance     create_date
alex     42           09/12/2014
john     35           09/22/2014
mike     12           09/10/2014
```

Does someone have an idea for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need a running total. LAG/LEAD is what you need here, assuming you are on 2012 or greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding the query for the the person who crossed particular count

```
   select A.name,sum(A.distance),A.create_date from (select name,distance,create_date 
   from table where create_date between @start_date and @end_date)A group by A.name,A.create_date
   having sum(A.distance)>@count
```

Those who doesnt cross

```
   select A.name,sum(A.distance),max(A.create_date) from (select name,distance,create_date 
   from table where create_date between @start_date and @end_date)A group by A.name
   having sum(A.distance)<@count
```

Comment: You missed "@count and return the date this was achieved"  So your query gives alex a count of 72 and date of 9/14, should be 42 and 9/12

Comment: Is it possible to modify the answer to have only two parameters: start_date and count.  So what I need is for the query to return the sum of distances after @tart_date, and to stop counting for each person when the distance JUST passes @count?

Comment: In this case u have to write a stored procedure and loop the count using cursor to achieve ur result.Refer this link http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/